# sort SCAN operation in Dynamodb

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-dynamodb

how to use order by 'token_no' in scan operation

```
$dynamodb = new AmazonDynamoDB();
$query = array(
    'TableName' => $this->token_table,
    'AttributesToGet' => array('token_no'),
    'ScanFilter' => array(
        'queue_id' => array(
            'ComparisonOperator' => AmazonDynamoDB::CONDITION_EQUAL,
            'AttributeValueList' => array(
                array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING => (string)$queue_id)
            )
        ),
        'queue_date' => array(
            'ComparisonOperator' => AmazonDynamoDB::CONDITION_EQUAL,
            'AttributeValueList' => array(
                array( AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING => (string)$date)
            )
        )
    ),
);

$scan_response = $dynamodb->scan($query);
```

Answer (score 3):

You **can not** specify the sort order for a `Scan` operation. The result is sorted by some internal representaton of the `HashKey`. So you can not know in which order the items will return.

Only `Query` operations return items in a defined order.

> Query results are always sorted by the range key. If the data type of the range key is Number, the results are returned in numeric order; otherwise, the results are returned in order of ASCII character code values. By default, the sort order is ascending. To reverse the order use the `ScanIndexForward` parameter set to `false`.
>
> From the [AWS DynamoDB Developer Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html)