# DynamoDB sort by specific field in Scan function

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I have data in DynamoDB:

```
data = []Data{
   {
       "Name": "foo",
       "Number: 12,
   },
   {
       "Name": "baz",
       "Number: 34,
   },
}

item, _:= attributevalue.MarshalMap(data)
_, err := dynamoDbClient.PutItem(context.TODO(), &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
    TableName: aws.String("tablename"), 
    Item: item,
})
```

Now I use `Scan` to paginate, filter and sort data. Paginate and filter are done, now I have problem with sort. I do not know how to sort by specific key form `item`, like `Number` or `Name` when I also paginate the data in the same time? Maybe someone has similar problem and solved it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sort SCAN operation in Dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266724/sort-scan-operation-in-dynamodb)

Comment: @fedonev I hoped that there is workaround for Scan :( Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In DynamoDB you can only sort by the sort-key attribute. Moreover, the data returned is only guaranteed to be sorted in its group by partition key (item collection). This essentially means you cannot retrieve a sorted order when you use `Scan` API.

Below is an example of how the data would be returned:

| pk | sk | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | some-data |
| 1 | b | some-data |
| 1 | c | some-data |
| 1 | z | some-data |
| 2 | a | some-data |
| 2 | g | some-data |
| 2 | l | some-data |
| 2 | z | some-data |

As you can see, the data is only sorted with relation to the partition key, so doing a `Scan` you cannot get all items sorted by sort key.